# Убрать с группы фотографий водянной знак?

Tags: photoshop, изображения

Как убрать водяной знак с группы фотографий? Водяной знак располагается по центру фотографий.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не по теме

Comment: @ VenZell Извините, а не соответствующего какой именно теме? По-моему, тема `photoshop` очень даже подходит для удаления водяного знака. А в чем еще убирать его? В php или в html или в javascript? Или Вы думаете, что в Photoshop нет средств автоматизации? Так я Вас обрадую - есть! Есть целый Action script, а при желании можно и на c++ писать плагины. Ну а то, что эта тема photoshop не сильно развита на stackoverflow, ну так это наша с Вами недоработка и печалька тех, кто в нее стучится за ответом.

Comment: Action Sript позволит автоматом сделать у группы картинок?

Comment: @MaxZS тема "photoshop без автоматизации" просто не входит в тематику ru.SO. Для темы "photoshop с автоматизацией" здесь не хватает как минимум упоминания того, что нужно программное решение, а ещё какого-нибудь кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стопроцентно и автоматизированно - никак. Для получения более-менее качественного результата необходимо знать алгоритм наложения водяного знака, а также его изначальный цвет, прозрачность и неплохо бы иметь сам исходник этого водяного знака. Если изначально это все делали Вы, а теперь Вам просто нужно убрать, то шансы свести заметность водяного знака к минимуму (но не убрать полностью) достаточно велики. Если же это чужая работа, то можно отрисовать знак, попытаться подобрать его цвет, прозрачность и эффект наложения, но результат будет заметен.